# How can I re-create an Ethereum Gnosis-Safe on Avalanche (lost funds)?

Tags: gnosis-safe, avalanche

I recently accidently bridged funds from an ETH Gnosis-Safe to AVAX without changing the destination address. As expected, the funds were bridged on AVAX under the same address as the ETH safe, but I don't believe I can access them without re-creating a safe on AVAX.

I've looked into the guide on loom for Safe 1.3.0, but it mentions that doesn't work with Avalanche:
https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741

However, the Intercom support on Gnosis's website indicated that "devs" confirmed it is possible to recreate a safe from ETH to AVAX.

The method above says "Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 43114" when I try it. Not really suprised that it doesnèt work since the proxy address is different.

I thought about trying the same method with the proper proxy, but didn't want to do it and accidently lose the funds.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to solve it? I have the same issue.

Comment: @JOY Hey, unfortunately not, was hoping the devs would pick it up one day, but nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this guide and it worked...
https://dev.to/carlomigueldy/deploy-the-same-gnosis-safe-address-in-multiple-networks-4md4

Not sure what is different from the main Gnosis Support one, but it hadn't worked for me... Maybe I was doing something wrong... Who knows...

Just needed to use contract interaction after that to recover the funds.

Comment: I followed but cannot send out the fund.

Comment: @JOY If you are able to load the interface:
https://app.safe.global/transactions/queue?safe=avax:0xYourAddressHere

You should be able to create a "new transaction" and then select "contract interaction". You can then use the ABI of the token you are trying to send out to transfer your funds.

For example, you can enter the DAI.e address and the the transfer method to send them to another wallet. Depending on what your assets are they should have an equivalent method.