# Cannot create the same Safe address on Avalanche C-Chain

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I created a Safe address on Ethereum here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xaee01e245addd3b07123f03209ad52b84401d274149583aa7775a77e07469393

Then I was able to create the same address on BNB and Polygon chains. But for Avalanche C-Chain, the Safe address is different with other chains.

https://snowtrace.io/tx/0xe70d551de8506b48472e190cbe52fd3e3e134d8c1a3ae698224c10dcb6d588d0

I checked and they have the same Hex data. So can I create the same Safe address on Avalanche? Or I cannot because the have different Gnosis Safe proxy factory address?

Update:
I tried to deploy the same Safe proxy factory address (althought it's not the provided one in Github) and was able to deploy the Safe with the same address. However, I cannot transfer the assets out:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The version of the Safe used for mainnet is not compatible with side chains, so you need to use other tools like https://github.com/5afe/safe-cli to get the funds out. More info: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/5267779-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover

Answer (score 0):

you had commented on my post with the same issue. I was able to fix it. See my answer below... Hopefully that works for you too...
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/149445/115903

Had to use contract interaction to transfer assets out.

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate, please use the flag system to mark it as duplicate.